# Save and load the position of dynamically created, draggable elements(jQuery-UI)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, dynamic, save, load

I am in the process of developing an offline web application that mimics a magnet board.

I can dynamicly create the draggable Items and drag them around the screen. **Now I want to be able to save  the positions and content(just one image per element) of my elements into a file and later load it again.**

I want it in a file because it needs to be interchangable between different users.

Here is the javascript of how i dynamicly create my elements:

```
$("#item1").mousedown(function (e){

var newpin = document.createElement("DIV");
var pinimage = document.createElement("IMG");

pinimage.setAttribute("src", "Media/2D_Container_Alfa.jpg");
pinimage.setAttribute("height", "70px");

newpin.setAttribute("position","relative");
newpin.setAttribute("top","20px");
newpin.setAttribute("left","140px");
newpin.setAttribute("display","block");

newpin.setAttribute("class", "draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle");
newpin.appendChild(pinimage);
document.body.appendChild(newpin);});
```

TLDR.: I want to save the configuration on my magnet board and be able to load previously saved configurations

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest you iterate over each of the elements you want to save and use `.position()` to get it's `top` and `left` values. Capture any other attributes you desire. You can then store all this in a Object or Array, and store that someplace you can read it from when loading.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider some newer code:

```
function makePin(event, t, l){
  var $pin = $("<div>", {
    class: "pin draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"
  }).css({
    position: "relative",
    top: (t !== undefined ? t + "px" : "20px"),
    left: (l !== undefined ? l + "px" : "140px"),
    disply: "block"
  }).appendTo(".pin-area");
  var $pinImage = $("<img>", {
    src: "Media/2D_Container_Alfa.jpg"
  }).css({
    height: "70px"
  }).appendTo($pin);
  return $pin;
}

function getPins(){
  var pins = [];
  $(".pin-area .pin").each(function(ind, el){
    var pos = $(el).offset();
    var imgSrc = $("img", el).attr("src");
    pins.push({
      top: pos.top,
      left: pos.left,
      src: imgSrc
    });
  });
  return pins;
}

$("#item1").mousedown(function (e){
  makePin(e);
});
```

Since you did not include any HTML in your post, I would consider the following in relationship to the code above:

```
<body>
  <div class="pin-area">
  </div>
</body>
```

You also did not indicate what would initiate the saving of this data once collected or how it would be loaded. one way to do this is to update once any drag action is completed, binding to `stop`. You also did not mention where you wanted to store this data. The following makes some assumptions that you will be using Draggable and LocalStorage.

```
$(".pin").on("dragstop", function(e, ui){
  localStorage.setItem("pins", JSON.stringify(getPins()));
});
```

This will update a locally stored variable with JSON text each time a pin is moved.

```
function loadPins(){
  var pins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItems("pins"));
  if(pins !== undefined){
    $.each(pins, function(k, v){
      makePin(null, v.top, v.left);
    });
  }
}
```

This function would then be able to load those pins. You'd want to execute this function just before you close your jQuery block. A small example of it all put together. You will need to do more testing and adjusting to fit your needs.

```js
$(function() {
  function makePin(event, t, l) {
    var $pin = $("<div>", {
      class: "pin draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"
    }).css({
      position: "relative",
      top: (t !== undefined ? t + "px" : "20px"),
      left: (l !== undefined ? l + "px" : "140px"),
      disply: "block"
    }).appendTo(".pin-area");
    var $pinImage = $("<img>", {
      src: $(".example-image").attr("src")
    }).css({
      height: "70px"
    }).appendTo($pin);
    $pin.draggable();
    return $pin;
  }

  function getPins() {
    var pins = [];
    $(".pin-area .pin").each(function(ind, el) {
      var pos = $(el).offset();
      var imgSrc = $("img", el).attr("src");
      pins.push({
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left,
        src: imgSrc
      });
    });
    return pins;
  }

  function loadPins() {
    var pins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItems("pins"));
    if (pins !== undefined) {
      $.each(pins, function(k, v) {
        makePin(null, v.top, v.left);
      });
    }
  }

  $(".pin").on("dragstop", function(e, ui) {
    localStorage.setItem("pins", JSON.stringify(getPins()));
  });

  $(".pin-area").mousedown(function(e) {
    makePin(e);
  });

  loadPins();
});
```

```css
.pin-area {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  background-image: url("https://www2.lbl.gov/assets/img/maps/sitemap.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="pin-area">
</div>
<p>Example Pin:</p><img class="example-image" style="height: 70px;" src="https://www.clker.com/cliparts/r/R/m/q/E/6/orange-pin-th.png">
```

Comment: You assumed my HTML code correctly, it's just a DIV with a class. So with your example I now have my data saved in the localStorage. Assuming I want to give the saved file with a specific configuration to another user, how would I go about that? I can only save one configuration at a time with your example code correct? And if i wanted to save more files I would just have to modify the setItem/getItem methods? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @MichaelWinkler you will have to determine the data storage type. Will it be a file? A database? A QR Code? When you make that decision will define how this script will then be able to save and load the data. LocalStorage is like a cookie. So it would keep it for that browser. You could make a function to read it out to a file for download: 'mypins.json' if you wanted. You can also write the data to a database which will need another server-side scripting language like PHP. With the limited details you provided, I was able to construct this example to answer the question. You do the rest.